# Partial string matching on large data set

Tags: python, pandas, difflib, fuzzywuzzy

So I have been working on this for a while and just haven't got any where and just not sure what to do.Fairly new to pandas and python.

Data set is actually 15,000 product names. All in different formats, some have multiple dashes up to 6, some hyphens, different lengths,The rows are product names with variants.

The code i'm using keeps returning only the first letter as oppose to the partial string when I use it on a large data set.

Works just fine on a small data set which I was using to test it.

I'm assuming this is happening because:

1. I haven't created a stop section when it matches a  full partial string
2. because its trying to match up words as oppose to individual characters  and stopping when it finds a difference.

What is the best way to overcome this on a **large data set**, what am I missing? or am I going to have to do this manual?

Original test data set

```
`1.star t-shirt-large-red
 2.star t-shirt-large-blue
 3.star t-shirt-small-red
 4.beautiful rainbow skirt small
 5.long maxwell logan jeans- light blue -32L-28W
 6.long maxwell logan jeans- Dark blue -32L-28W`
```

Desired data set/output:

```
 `COL1                             COL2         COL3    COL4
  1[star t-shirt]                  [large]      [red]    NONE
  2[star t-shirt]                  [large]      [blue]   NONE
  3[star t-shirt]                  [small]      [red]    NONE
  4[beautiful rainbow skirt small] [small]       NONE   NONE
  5[long maxwell logan jeans]      [light blue] [32L]  [28W]
  6[long maxwell logan jeans]      [Dark blue]  [32L]  [28W]`
```

Here is the code I was helped with in a previous question I asked:

```
`df['onkey'] = 1
 df1 = pd.merge(df[['name','onkey']],df[['name','onkey']], on='onkey')
 df1['list'] = df1.apply(lambda x:[x.name_x,x.name_y],axis=1)
 from os.path import commonprefix
 df1['COL1'] = df1['list'].apply(lambda x:commonprefix(x))
 df1['COL1_num'] = df1['COL1'].apply(lambda x:len(x))
 df1 = df1[(df1['COL1_num']!=0)]
 df1 = df1.loc[df1.groupby('name_x')['COL1_num'].idxmin()]
 df = df.rename(columns ={'name':'name_x'})
 df = pd.merge(df,df1[['name_x','COL1']],on='name_x',how ='left')`


`df['len'] = df['COL1'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
 df['other'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.name_x[x.len:],axis=1)
 df['COL1'] = df['COL1'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
 df['COL1'] = df['COL1'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1] if x[-1]=='-' else x)
 df['other'] = df['other'].apply(lambda x:x.split('-'))
 df = df[['COL1','other']]
 df = pd.concat([df['COL1'],df['other'].apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)`

`                                      COL1            0     1    2
0                   star t-shirt        large   red  NaN
1                   star t-shirt        large  blue  NaN
2                   star t-shirt        small   red  NaN
3  beautiful rainbow skirt small                NaN  NaN
4       long maxwell logan jeans  light blue    32L  28W
5       long maxwell logan jeans   Dark blue    32L  28W`
```

***************update*****************

1. This is your input list of product,some have variants and some don't.
2. When searching for duplicates strings to determine what are the products with variants and products without variants;nothing comes up because they are all seen as unique values due to  the variants being added on at the end of the string.
3. So what I would like to do is group the partial or similar strings together(the longest match), extract the longest matching string within the group and then put the differences into other columns.

   4. If  the product /string is unique just print into the column with the extracted longest string.

      `star t-shirt-large-red
         star t-shirt-large-blue
         star t-shirt-small-red
         beautiful rainbow skirt small
         long maxwell logan jeans- light blue -32L-28W
         long maxwell logan jeans- Dark blue -32L-28W
         Organic  and natural candy - 3 Pack - Mint
         Organic  and natural candy - 3 Pack - Vanilla
         Organic  and natural candy - 3 Pack - Strawberry
         Organic  and natural candy - 3 Pack - Chocolate
         Organic  and natural candy - 3 Pack - Banana
         Organic  and natural candy - 3 Pack - Cola
         Organic  and natural candy - 12 Pack Assorted
         Morgan T-shirt Company - Small/Medium-Blue
         Morgan T-shirt Company - Medium/Large-Blue
         Morgan T-shirt Company - Medium/Large-red
         Morgan T-shirt Company - Small/Medium-Red
         Morgan T-shirt Company - Small/Medium-Green
         Morgan T-shirt Company - Medium/Large-Green
         Nelly dress leopard small`

      `col1                          col2                 col3       col4 
         star t-shirt                  large                red

         star t-shirt                  large                blue

         star t-shirt                  small                red

         beautiful rainbow skirt       small

         Long maxwell logan jeans      light blue            32L        28W
         Long maxwell logan jeans      Dark blue             32L        28W
         Organic  and natural candy     3 Pack               Mint 
         Organic  and natural candy     3 Pack               Vanilla

         Organic  and natural candy     3 Pack               Strawberry

         Organic  and natural candy     3 Pack               Chocolate

         Organic  and natural candy     3 Pack               Banana

         Organic  and natural candy     3 Pack               Cola 
         Organic  and natural candy     12 Pack              Assorted 
         Morgan T-shirt Company         Small/Medium         Blue 
         Morgan T-shirt Company         Medium/Large         Blue 
         Morgan T-shirt Company         Medium/Large         Red

         Morgan T-shirt Company         Small/Medium         Red

         Morgan T-shirt Company         Small/Medium         Green

         Morgan T-shirt Company         Medium/Large         Green

         Nelly dress                    Leopard              Small

         Bijoux

         Princess PJ-set

         Lemon tank top                 Yellow    Medium`

Comment: What does partial string matching or a "full partial string" mean in this context? It's not very clear how string matching relates to your desired output. It looks like you simply want to format a string input into a Pandas dataframe. Also, the data types are not clear in your desired output. For example, what does `[small]` mean?

Comment: @Ataxias meaning  find  strings that have partial matches  and group them together and extract the longest matching string within  the group. Small is a variant for that product. I already have the strings saved into a dataframe already. example  df['name']

Answer (score 2):

Constructing a DataFrame df as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append(['1.star t-shirt-large-red'])
df = df.append(['2.star t-shirt-large-blue'])
df = df.append(['4.beautiful rainbow skirt small'])
df = df.append(['5.long maxwell logan jeans- light blue -32L-28W'])
df = df.append(['6.long maxwell logan jeans- Dark blue -32L-28W'])

df.columns = ['Product']
```

The following code

(a) strips any whitespace,

(b) splits by the period ('.') and grabs what follows,

(c) replaces 't-shirt' with 'tshirt' because of further operations (change this back if you want after the operation)

(d) splits again by '-' and expands to give your dataframe.

```
df['Product'].str.strip().str.split('.').str.get(1).str.replace('t-shirt', 'tshirt').str.split('-', expand = True)
```

Output:

```
                               0             1     2     3
0                    star tshirt         large   red  None
0                    star tshirt         large  blue  None
0  beautiful rainbow skirt small          None  None  None
0       long maxwell logan jeans   light blue    32L   28W
0       long maxwell logan jeans    Dark blue    32L   28W
```

Given the inconsistency in nomenclature for your product, there will be edge-cases that are missed (ex : `beautiful rainbow skirt small`). You may have to fish them out again.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly, so  how do I construct the dataframe  for 15,000 products in that way in pandas or in excel before I import the csv. Im sorry if it seems like a silly questions but I have always made it by hand for a few  things.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: ,so I done what you had stated but the code doesn't return anything on my data.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which is quite simple to understand, debug and flexibly extend is the following:

Consider that your initial product names are held in a list called `strings`.

Then **the solution is the following line**:

```
mydf = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([make_row(row, 4)], columns=['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3', 'COL4']) for row in strings],  ignore_index=True)
```

where we have defined the parsing function `make_row` to be:

```
def make_row(string, num_cols):
    cols = [item.strip() for item in string[2:].split('-')] # ignore numbering, split on hyphen and strip whitespace
    if len(cols) < num_cols:
        cols += [np.nan]*(num_cols - len(cols)) # fill with NaN missing values
    return cols
```

The first line defining `cols` could also be simply `cols = string.split('-')`, in which case you could do the formatting afterwards with:

```
mydf.applymap(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else str.strip(x))
```

Now in your case, I see that there is a hyphen in some of your product names, in which case you might want to 'sanitize' them in advance (or inside `make_row`, as you wish), with something like:

```
strings = [item.replace('t-shirt', 'tshirt') for item in strings]
```

**Example input**:

```
strings = ['1.one-two-three', '2. one-two', '3.one-two-three-four', '4.one - two -three  -four ']
```

**Output**:

```
  COL1 COL2   COL3  COL4
0  one  two  three   NaN
1  one  two    NaN   NaN
2  one  two  three  four
3  one  two  three  four
```

**Output for question's data** (after correcting typo for item 4):

```
                       COL1        COL2  COL3 COL4
0               star tshirt       large   red  NaN
1               star tshirt       large  blue  NaN
2               star tshirt       small   red  NaN
3   beautiful rainbow skirt       small   NaN  NaN
4  long maxwell logan jeans  light blue   32L  28W
5  long maxwell logan jeans   Dark blue   32L  28W
```

**Edit:**

If you additionally want to "group" the items together, then you can:

a) Use `sort_values` ([pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)) on the column COL1 after you get a dataframe as described above to simply display the rows corresponding to the same product the one after the other, or

b) use `group_by` to actually get a grouped dataframe like this:

```
grouped_df = mydf.groupby("COL1")
```

This will allow you to get each group like this:

```
grouped_df.get_group("star tshirt")
```

Producing following output:

```
          COL1   COL2  COL3 COL4
0  star tshirt  large   red  NaN
1  star tshirt  large  blue  NaN
2  star tshirt  small   red  NaN
```

Comment: I also tried your method but it just returned columns  that would look like something like this s=df['name]     s.str.split("-",n=7,expand = True)

Comment: Can you check the example Input - Output in my answer? What do you get for this example, and how does it differ from your data?

Comment: will do that now.

Comment: So it differs from my data  :1) it removes the first and second character in the string. 2) It doesnt group the longest string together it just splits it by "-" into named columns.(col1,col2, etc)

Comment: For 1: This is because of `[2:]` in the line `cols = [item.strip() for item in string[2:].split('-')]`; feel free to remove it. I put it there because in your example input, each line started with a number and a dot, which you wanted to remove later.

Comment: For 2: If I have understood correctly what you mean by "group", then you may get what you want by either: a) Use `sort_values` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) on the column COL1 after you get a dataframe as described above to simply display the rows corresponding to the same product the one after the other, or b) use `group_by` to actually get a grouped dataframe like this: `grouped_df = mydf.groupby("COL1")`. This will allow you to get each group like this: `grouped_df.get_group("star tshirt")`